# I have two columns sales_agent and deal_stage in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns sales_agent and deal_stage, sales_agent contains names of agents and deal_stage contains 3 different values like lost,won and in_progress,

I want to find all sales_agent who never lost did at deal_stage.
I have tried this

```
nine=products_pipeline_and_teams[~(products_pipeline_and_teams['deal_stage']=='Lost')]
```

But it just displays sales_agent with won or in_progress,I want to find sales_agent who never had 'lost' value.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the code that you have, you are going through each row and deciding whether or not to keep that row based off of the `dead_stage` column-value. As you say, this is just going to show rows where the value is something else. If I understand right, you are trying to filter out the agents who have ever lost - so if the agent has won and has lost, we also want to remove that win row.

You can accomplish this by making a list of `losers`, and then filtering your dataframe on that list, which will be names of people who have ever lost

```py
losers = list(df['agent'][df['deal_stage']=='Lost']) # this makes a list of values in the agent column, based off of if the value in 'deal_stage' is lost
df = df[~df['agent'].isin(losers)] # this returns all columns, but filtered to where the 'agent' column only has values that are not in the losers list
```